# Write bytes to a stram -what happen to the data?

Tags: tcp

if an application write bytes to a port , and no one reads the data from that port , what happen to the data ?
suppose one application write a char message to a port every minutes (the message has end tag) , and the application the should read from that port is down , will the messages will be lost ?

Comment: Packet Loss - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss

Comment: Java or any other programming language are completely unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If the port is closed (over a TCP/IP or UDP/IP network), the packets will be dropped, and the data will be lost. If it's open, but the receiving application just never reads it in, it will sit in the buffer until the app terminates, at which point it is lost. With local IPC, say, a pipe, the data just sits around in the read buffer until the read end of the pipe is closed, at which point it is lost.

TL;DR: It's lost.

Comment: Also, in a TCP/IP network, if the port is closed, the sender may receive an `RST` packet (although this doesn't necessarily happen - the receiver can just ignore unsolicited traffic, or some firewall may block it, etc.)